# syslog and LOCAL0..7

Tags: c++, linux, syslog

We have about 10 different daemons for which we would like to use `syslog` logging. It looks like that for custom applications you're supposed to use `LOCAL0`..`LOCAL7` facilities. Well, how can one then differentiate between those 10 daemons if he has only 8 possible "sockets"?

For example, if we'd like to have one `/var/log/daemon<x>` file per each daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use different `syslog` facilities for that. Instead, pass `LOG_PID` option to [openlog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog) and configure appropriately your logger daemon thru [syslog.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf), or perhaps use [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) or some other syslogger (there are many of them). `openlog` has a `ident` argument which can be used by logger dameons for discrimination & filtering of log messages.

And alternative would be to conventionally decide that logging should go to some application specific file under `/var/log` (i.e. use just `<stdio.h>` with `fopen`, `fprintf` but don't forget `fflush`). This is what many Linux servers (`exim4`, `lighttpd`, `Xorg`, ...) are doing. See also the [Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) which defines conventions.

Comment: Passing `LOG_PID` is easy, but with `PID` as a dynamically assigned value, how can one write some rules to split logging into 10 different files?

Comment: You are passing an ident to openlog. I've edited my answer to explain more. Just configure your logger for various values of that ident.

Comment: Thanks, so there CAN be some static/fixed `syslog.conf` rules depending on this `ident` passed to `openlog`, saying "if `ident` is `somewhat` pass logging to that file", right?

Comment: At least some logger daemons are able to handle the ident... And as I already said, you can log directly to a file under /var/log/ and it is usual practice.

Comment: We have to use `syslog` so no `stdio`, that's why I'm asking if `rsyslog` can handle it.